# Unusual Error in inserting data into database

Tags: php, mysql

i am simply inserting the data from a form using PHP into a MYSQL Table but i am getting an unusual error.My code is

```
$q1="insert into product (category,image,name,desc) values ('$cat','$pname','$name','$desc')";
        $res1=$con->query($q1);
        if($res1)
        {
            some logic;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "error";
        }
```

i am unusually getting the else part executed even if the code is sytactically correct.i have checked and verified the values of all the PHP variables.i am using OOP style PHP for database connection.Also,on executing the query in PHPmyadmin too using random values i am getting the following error:

SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO Product( category, image, name, DESC )
VALUES (
'dsdsd', 'sddsd', 'sd', 'it is a nice'
)
```

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc)
VALUES
('dsdsd','sddsd','sd','it is a nice')' at line 1
```

Comment: `desc` is a reserved keyword, surround with back-ticks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DESC is a reserved key word you need to use backticks as

```
INSERT INTO Product( category, image, name, `DESC` )
```

Answer (score 2):

`DESC` Is a keyword in `MySQL`, You need to put that in Back ticks ``

```
INSERT INTO Product( category, image, name, `DESC` )
VALUES (
'dsdsd', 'sddsd', 'sd', 'it is a nice'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`DESC` is a mysql keyword. You need to use backtick like this:-

```
INSERT INTO Product( category, image, name, `DESC` )
```